# Subtract vectors for each row?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following arrays:

```
a = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(5,3))
b = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(2,3))
```

How can I concisely subtract each row from `b` from each row in `a` such that the result is of shape `(5,2)`. Letting the result be `c`, `c[i,j]` is the euclidean distance between `a[i,:]` and `b[j,:]`.

I can get this behavior when there is only 1 column:

```
a = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(5,1))
b = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(2,1))
print((a-b.T).shape)
```

Comment: No I don't think so :) I have now updated the OP with a case where I get the behavior I want.

Comment: Sorry, cannot understand. `c[i,j]` is a scalar, isn't it? And `a[i,:] - b[j,:]` is a vector. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. Sorry! Anyways, the case I have shown where there is only 1 column shows the behavior I want(just replacing 1 column with 3)

Comment: @Itay Ahhhhh, yes I want the norm which is a scalar. Yikes :) I updated the question.

Comment: that seems `cdist(a, b)` with `from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist`

Comment: your example output for 1 column case is not Euclidean distance by the way. That's not a distance as it can be negative.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I understand, but the behavior should be the same, just replacing subtraction with norm :)

Comment: I think you could do it with a kronecker product of ones array of correct shape to get two 3D arrays that you can directly subtract and then apply the norm along the 3rd dimension.  Not sure if that's the best way, and I don't know the details, but it will at least be "concise" and vectorized.  Probably some straightforward for loops would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, I haven't looked at the result too carefully, but this should at least give you an idea.

Something like this:

```
a = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(5,3))
b = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(2,3))
aa = np.kron(np.ones((1,2,1)), a.reshape((5,1,3)))
bb = np.kron(np.ones((5,1,1)), b.reshape((1,2,3)))
aa.shape == bb.shape == (5,2,3) # rows are now axis 2
c = np.linalg.norm(aa-bb, axis=2) # shape = (5,2)
```

Of course this makes huge intermediate results.  I think broadcasting might be better, but I'm not very familiar with that.